# hue to rgb google maps marker

Tags: android, rgb, google-maps-android-api-2

I create my google map markers with a hue color

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/BitmapDescriptorFactory#defaultMarker(float)

The hue of the marker. Value must be greater or equal to 0 and less than 360.

Is there a way to convert this hue witch is a float to a rgb color ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this code:

```
float hue = 180.0f;
int color = Color.HSVToColor(new float[] { hue, 1.0f, 1.0f });
```

More info:

```
/**
 * Convert HSV components to an ARGB color. Alpha set to 0xFF.
 *     hsv[0] is Hue [0 .. 360)
 *     hsv[1] is Saturation [0...1]
 *     hsv[2] is Value [0...1]
 * If hsv values are out of range, they are pinned.
 * @param hsv  3 element array which holds the input HSV components.
 * @return the resulting argb color
*/
public static int HSVToColor(float hsv[]) {
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, this wah hard but I found